# Use a button to change the orientation of the iPhone

Tags: cocoa-touch

Is there a way to change the orientation of the iPhone using a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my new account btw..

Right, I got this sorted by apply the transformations to what I wanted to show when the button was clicked. It was to show a scrollview with applied animations to objects within the scroll view.

Answer (score 2):

No. flip the phone, the orientation changes. Leave it at that, or you'll ruin the integrity of the phone.

Comment: While I agree 95% of the time, domness could have a good reason - e.g. the app is to be used while strapped to your arm and random orientation changes will only frustrate your user.  I'm doing the same thing with a workout tracking app :)

Comment: but...if it's strapped to your arm...you won't be looking at it much anyway? What would be the point of pressing a button, changing the orientation, then turning the phone anyway to view said orientation? Isn't that kind of, pointless?

Comment: Sometimes while I'm relaxing and browsing with Safari, I hold the phone at a weird angle, which causes it to change orientations. I wish there was a way to lock the orientation. In the case of Safari, a button would do nicely. That's just one example though... automatic orientation changes can suck.

Comment: I noticed that too. I don't develop for the iPhone, im just a user. When I first gone the phone that I bought myself for Christmas, I noticed the accelerometer only works when the phone is in the "up" position. It makes sense. But sometimes, I'll have it on my lap (when in the bathroom)...

Comment: and I cant change the orientation without first grabbing it and turning it up. Gravity sucks, sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

sometimes we need to show our app in the correct orientation, even if there is not direct way on doing what domness want, you can look at [this SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314382/how-to-force-a-screen-orientation-in-specific-view-controllers) and see some responses.

P.S. @ domness, try to search for what you need before posting a new question.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to reorient? You can change the position of the status bar with `UIApplication -setStatusBarOrientation:animated:`; rearrange your UI with the proper transformations and you'll pretty much have it.

Answer (score 0):

You can force an orientation change, but only using an unsupported, private API. If this is something you'd like Apple to make public, you should [file an enhancement request](http://bugreporter.apple.com).